# Can I have differently colored comments in Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, comments, syntax-highlighting

In the past I have used Notepad++, which enables me to have different colors for comments depending on how I write them e.g.:

```
// Two backspaces = first color
/// Three backspaces = second color
/* Multi-line comment
   = third color
*/
```

I find this very useful for differentiating between different types of comments e.g. code comments, documentation, file organisation comments, etc.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this in Visual C++ 2010? I had managed to (partially) do it in VS2005 somehow, but it was a workaround and I've forgotten the trick, and can't seem to find the answer again on Google.

Comment: Look for "documentation comment"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I found in my version of Visual Studio 2010:

*Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors*

Then:

- *Comment* is for `//` and `/* */`
- *Documentation comment* (or *XML documentation comment*) is for `///`

The others comment options seems to be useless for C++

Comment: That's rather interesting, I don't see _Documentation comment_ in VS2012.

Comment: It seems they've made a lot of changes (I don't have VS2012). The simple test is to assign a different color to each comment style, and then test it on all different types of comments in C++.

Comment: @Synxis I think this is what I did in VS2005. However, I can't seem to find _Documentation comment_ in VS2010, only _Comment_. Any idea why it might be missing?

Comment: Can you post the name of all different types of comments proposed by your vs1020 ?

Comment: @Synxis I know it must be somewhere, because if I change the color of _Comment_, it doesn't alter the color of comments which start with ///

Comment: It is near "Comment", maybe if you post what I said previously I can recognize the one you're searching for (although on my vs, it is what is said in my answer).

Comment: @Synxis CSS Comment, HTML Comment, Script Comment, VB XML Comment (listed twice), XAML Comment, XML Comment, XML Doc Comment. I'll have a play around with them all, unless you already know the right one.

Comment: @Synxis Great, thanks - came across the same answer at exactly the same time as you posted.

Comment: Sadly they don't apply to Javascript xml doc comments :(